# is it possible to anchor-scrolling inside a scrolled div?

Tags: reactjs

i am using react-scrollable-anchor npm to scroll to #hash elements inside big div,
but now i have been needed to wrap the whole div with a scroll of 85% of the page (for making the footer stable without the div getting there), and it cause the package broke.
i'm still getting /#element} in the url, but i guess that cause all of the text in the div its on the same spot on the page, react-scrollable-anchor dont recognize that the scroll should be done inside the manual scroll and not in the window scroll anymore...
there is way to this manually or other npm that may work in this case (react-scroll isnt helpful too)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without usage of any libary

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const wrapperContext = createContext()

function WrapperProvider({ children }) {
  let wrapperRef = useRef(null)
  let history = useHistory()


  let getPosition = elemID => {
        let x = 0
        let y = 0
        let element = document.getElementById(elemID)
        while (element && element.className != 'main-scroll-wrapper') {
            x += element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft
            y += element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop
            element = element.offsetParent
        }

        return { x, y }
    }

    let scrollTo = (...props) =>
        wrapperRef.current ? wrapperRef.current.scrollTo(...props) : setTimeout(() => scrollTo(...props), 0)

    let scrollToElem = async (elemID, pathname) => {
        if (typeof elemID != 'string') elemID = ''
        if (typeof pathname != 'string') pathname = '/'

        await history.push(pathname)
        let pos
        if (elemID) pos = getPosition(elemID)

        return !!elemID.length
            ? pos
                ? scrollTo({
                        behavior: 'smooth',
                        top: pos.y
                  })
                : setTimeout(() => scrollToElem(elemID, pathname), 100)
            : scrollTo({
                    top: 0,
                    behavior: 'smooth'
              })
    }
    return <wrapperContext.Provider value={{ scrollTo, scrollToElem, wrapperRef }}>{children}</wrapperContext.Provider>
}

export { wrapperContext, WrapperProvider }
```

wrap scroll area with context, destruct `wrapperRef` to be relevant div (in my case it is classname 'main-scroll-wrapper'), and `scrollTo` or `scrollToElem` gonna work like a chram